# FFMPEG for android in Windows not successfully compile

Tags: android, bash, shell, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am trying to compile FFMPEG for android in Windows 8.1 but i got error at 32 line in build_android.sh

**./build_android.sh: line 32: syntax error: unexpected end of file**

when i execute command in cygwin

**chmod +x build_android.sh**

**./build_android.sh**

If you are knows steps to compile ffmpeg for android in windows and how to use ffmpeg in android then pleas reply me.

I am referencing .
http://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/downloads/Developing_Multimedia_Applications_with_NDK.pdf
,

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Android and

http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9

**build_android.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=E:/android-ndk-r9d
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows
function build_one { ./configure \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--disable-shared \
--enable-static \
--disable-doc \
--enable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--enable-avdevice \
--disable-doc \
--disable-symver \
--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--target-os=linux \
--arch=arm \
--enable-cross-compile \
--sysroot=$SYSROOT \
--extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
--extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install }
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
make instal }
```

to

```
make install
}
```

or

```
make install; }
```

Because that way, you are passig `}` as a second argument to `make`, and your function build_one doesn't have closing `}`.

#### Edit

Can you try this instead?

```
NDK=E:/android-ndk-r9d
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
./configure \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--disable-shared \
--enable-static \
--disable-doc \
--enable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--enable-avdevice \
--disable-doc \
--disable-symver \
--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--target-os=linux \
--arch=arm \
--enable-cross-compile \
--sysroot=$SYSROOT \
--extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
--extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install
```

Comment: ./configure: line 9: $'\r': command not found
): No such file or directoryg: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C
': not a valid identifierort: `LC_ALL
./configure: line 13: $'\r': command not found
./configure: line 16: $'\r': command not found
./configure: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
'/configure: line 17: `try_exec(){

Comment: You must save your script with unix line endings (`\n`), not Windows/DOS ones (`\r\n`).

Comment: Error message says that ./configure have DOS line endings, check this file.

Comment: how to check it it's ending with DOS line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58689/discussion-between-prakash-ubhadiya-and-iokanuon).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as build_android.sh i tested it and it worked with me

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=D:/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10d
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows
function build_one
{
./configure \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--disable-shared \
--enable-static \
--disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-avdevice \
--disable-doc \
--disable-symver \
--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--target-os=linux \
--arch=arm \
--enable-cross-compile \
--sysroot=$SYSROOT \
--extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
--extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install
}
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```

you need also to run this commands :

```
dos2unix build_android.sh
chmod +x build_android.sh
./build_android.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check line ending (use dos2unix  to fix that)
2. $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG - check if this variable doesn't contain unclosed quotas/brackets.